# Aptana will not install on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: installation, aptana3

When I try to install Aptana Studio, I get an error message

Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error.

I am then told that Aptana Studio setup ended prematurely bacause of an error. The installer then shuts down without installing the application.

I have installed nodejs, but still get this error.

Doug

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just go to https://nodejs.org/en/ , download and install node.js. Afterwards the installation of Aptana should work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. I tried that. I tried both the node-v4.2 and the node-v5.3 versions and neither made it where aptana studio 3 would install. It does not appear to look to see if I already have the software but rather it goes to download it. I think the installer setup is going to the wrong url to download the software (maybe).